# Iterator class method can not be reached in main

Tags: java, data-structures

I tried to reach that ArrayIterator class with iterator() method. but I can not use setValue method inside of main. It can not see that method. How can i make it visible in main? Can someone please help me?( I added other methods in the ArrayIterator.)

```
public class ArrayIterator implements Iterator<E> {
        int current = 1;  

        
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return current < n;
        }

        
        public E next() {
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
            System.out.println(getSize());
            System.out.println(getHeap()[current]);
            return heap[current++];
        }

        public E setValue(E item){
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
            E result = heap[n];
            heap[n] = item;
            return result;
        }
    }
@Override
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
       return new ArrayIterator();
}
```

Also my main class;

```
Heap<Integer> j = new Heap<>();
    
Iterator<Integer> iter = j.iterator();
```

Comment: Shouldn't the name of the class be `ArrayIterator<E>`?  Or is this an inner class of some other class that's defined `E`?

Comment: yes correct, it is a inner class of another class.

Comment: What happens if you change the signature of `iterator` to `public ArrayIterator iterator()` as well as the data type of the `iter` variable in `main`?

Comment: Okay, I did what you said. It worked correct. Thank you.